# email contact form - can reach success page manually even if form wasn't submitted - how to stop

Tags: php, redirect, contact-form

Here's my setup for an email contact form:

```
www.example.com/includes/contact_form.php
www.example.com/includes/contact_submit.php
www.example.com/contact/
```

/contact/ includes contact_form.php, and the form points to contact_submit.php to run.

When contact_submit.php successfully sends the mail, it does a redirect back to /contact/ but includes a $_GET variable.

```
header('Location: /contact/index.php?success=yup');
```

Then in contact_form.php I have:

```
if (isset($_GET['success'])) { echo 'Your message has been received etc'; exit(); }
```

Everything works fine. I made it this way so that the form couldn't be F5/refresh resubmitted, and it is successful in that.

However, anyone can access the success page at any time by manually entering the url, even if they don't submit the form. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [referrer page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) if you want, and throw an error or redirect if it is not the form page, but it is not so good. You can also check whether the fields and form name have been posted.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: I don't think I can check the form fields because after the header from contact_submit.php is sent they are gone, right? I guess HTTP_REFERER would be my only option (that's all I can find in searches too). That makes me think that maybe it's ok to just leave it how it is. If someone wants to bang their head against the success page, have at it... it's not wastin' my time! :) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes he can use the HTTP_REFERER, but it very bad solution and not clean. HTTP_REFERER can be changed with send HTTP HEADERS. Just use a sessions to store user requests and your response to access it in another scripts or after redirect, all flash components in frameworks works on this logic. Look below i had prepared a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse.
Use sessions for that:

```
class ResponseLog {

    private function __construct(){}


    public static function hasMessages(){
       return (isset($_SESSION['response']['messages']) && !empty($_SESSION['response']['messages'])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function setResponse(array $response){
         $_SESSION['response'] = $response;
    }

    public static function getLastResponse(){
         $response = isset($_SESSION['response'])) ? $_SESSION['response'] : null;
         @unset($_SESSION['response']);
         return $response;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['form'])){
   //validation and all to proccess request goes here

   if(!$valid){
       $response = array('request' => $_POST,'messages' => array('Incorrect email','Please enter forename'),'url' => '/my/form/where/it/happen/'); 
   }
   else {       
      $response = array('messages' => array('Success'),'url' => '/my/form/where/it/happen/');
   }

   ResponseLog::setResponse($response);
   //redirect to contact form
}
```

In success page or fail:

```
if(ResponseLog::hasMessages()){
   $response = ResponseLog::getLastResponse();
   foreach($response['messages'] as $message){
       echo $message;
   }
}
```

With this you can store everything user does and can work with data as you need.

I hope this help :)

Warn: I wrote it from mind, so it's untested code and it can be implemented better it's just for view how to work with user session and responses.

PS: But is a lot of ways how to do it, for example see flash messages in some framework and you will be see how it works with sessions etc.